# I found this bug in my code that i created to get the highest value from 2 integers and the variable is assigning itself a value

Tags: c++

I'm starting out to learn C++ and I'm a bit clueless as to what might be happening here. when I run the program and enter 2 equal inputs the int variable-result, automatically assigns itself the value, when it should not because none of the if statements are fulfilled.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

// this is the function to find the highest value among 2.
int MaxNum(int Num1, int Num2) {
  int result;
  string asdf;

  if (Num1 > Num2) {
    result = Num1;
  } else if (Num1 == Num2) {
    asdf = "equal inputs";
  } else if (Num2 > Num1) {
    result = Num2;
  }
  // here if the 2 given values are equal the variable result, should not be
  // assigned any value but when it is tested, it automatically assigns 
  //itself the input value.
   
  
  cout << result;
  cout << asdf;
}

int main() {
  int Uno;
  int Dos;

  cout << "enter 2 nos and ill tell the highest.";
  cin >> Uno;
  cin >> Dos;

  MaxNum(Uno, Dos);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to set result when the inputs are equal. Also your function has undefined behavior  in that it promises to return an integer but does not.

Comment: If they are equal, your `result` variable has not been initialized. The resulting behavior is undefined (it will most likely print some number). If you want it to print some specific number, initialize the variable to it before the `if`s.

Comment: if so why is not taking a random value but always takes the value that i input, like if i input 5 and 5 the result variable will output 5 and not a random number.

Comment: i got around this problem tho now. just used an if else condition in the end, so that the result variable would only be printed if the 2 input values were unequal.

Comment: Undefined behavior says anything can happen when you violate the rules of the language. By making use of an uninitialized variable you are violating the rules of the language.

Comment: thanks for ur help drescherjm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a variable, it will always have some value. This value, if you do not assign one, can be anything - just whatever value happens to be in the memory where it is defined. So you might see the number you inputted here, but that can be just a coincidence, or caused by some more complicated reasons on how programs use and recycle memory (because of how the stack is built up, but that is out of scope here). Either way, you cannot count on this.

nb- it is good practice to always initialize your variables (for example `int result = 0`). If you don't do that, bugs can get hard to reproduce when you start building more complicated programs.

Comment: This is what happens in practice for dumb compilers.  Smarter compilers assume that any branch that reads the variable without setting it first is never taken.  see https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/2517349.2522728

Comment: @Ben Voigt I did not know about that. Do I assume correctly that this only happens when optimization flags (like -O2 in g++) are turned on?

Comment: There are no valid assumptions about undefined behavior.  The only rule is that there are no rules.